# Parenthesized subfigure references except when already in parenthesis

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref

I would like to style my subfigure references as `Fig. 1(a)` in running text and `(Fig. 1a)` when parenthetical. The subfigure labels are created using [this code](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.text.tex/zGyopj7VOTM). (I would prefer to use `subcaption` like [in this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/149425/85604), but it causes a warning with the severely outdated journal class I'm stuck with.)

It is easy enough to get the first format with `\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{\thefigure(\alph{subfigure})}`, and I tried to follow [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/263532/85604) for the second step, but no matter what I try, it does not seem to work.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

% Sub-figure references b/c class is broken. See link above.
\makeatletter
\newcounter{subfigure}[figure]
\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{\thefigure(\alph{subfigure})}
\newcommand{\subfigure}{%
    \H@refstepcounter{subfigure}%
    \ifHy@hypertexnames%
            \hyper@makecurrent\@captype%
    \else%
            \global\let\@currentHref\hc@currentHref%
    \fi%
}
\makeatother

% Special format when within enclosing parentheses
\newcommand{\crefp}[1]{%
  \begingroup%
    \renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{\thefigure\alph{subfigure}}%
    (\cref{#1})%
  \endgroup%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \framebox[\textwidth]{Something}
  \caption{Caption}
  \label{fig:example}
  \subfigure\label{fig:example-1}
\end{figure}

Some text referencing the figure: \cref{fig:example},
and in parentheses: \crefp{fig:example}.
Some text referencing the subfigure: \cref{fig:example-1},
and in parentheses: \crefp{fig:example-1}.
\end{document}
```

The result is:

```
Some text referencing the figure: fig. 1, and in parentheses: (fig. 1). Some
text referencing the subfigure: fig. 1(a), and in parentheses: (fig. 1(a)).
```

I also tried messing with `\p@subfigure` instead or adding an extra macro around everything, but have so far not been successful.

(Note: I also could have left hyperref or cleveref out of the MWE, but since they do magical things with references and I'm go to use them anyway, I left them in.)